# Kibana don't store the right data into the right fiels

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Ok so now I've my mapping into kibana.
Here's my mapping:

```
PUT logstash-2019.05.09
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "index": {
          "_index": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "_type": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        },
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "ip": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "extension": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "response": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "geo": {
          "coordinates": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          },
          "src": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "dest": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "srcdest": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "utc_time": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "referer": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "agent": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "clientip": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "bytes": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "host": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "request": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "url": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "@message": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "spaces": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "xss": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "links": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "relatedContent": {
          "url": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "og:type": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "og:title": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "og:description": {
            "type": ""
          },
          "og:url": {
            "type": ""
          },
          "article:published_time": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "article:modified_time": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "article:section": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "article:tag": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "og:image": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "og:image:height": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "og:image:width": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "og:site_name": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "twitter:title": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "twitter:description": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "twitter:card": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "twitter:image": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "twitter:site": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        },
        "machine": {
          "os": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "ram": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't know why, Kibana don't store the right information into the right field. He just put all the information into a message field. I think it's because I've a dynamic mapping by default, I'm not really sure. Here's the result :

[Result (table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Qab.png)
result (json):

```
    {
  "_index": "logstash-2019.05.09",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "9zfam2oBWngGU4Wy3Id5",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2019-05-09T09:09:32.167Z",
    "path": "/home/secunix/logs/TestLogPourMapping_09_05.json",
    "message": "{\"@timestamp\":\"2019-05-07T09:56:33.996Z\",\"ip\":\"181.144.250.19\",\"extension\":\"jpg\",\"response\":\"200\",\"geo\":{\"coordinates\":{\"lat\":44.12326,\"lon\":-123.2186856},\"src\":\"IN\",\"dest\":\"CN\",\"srcdest\":\"IN:CN\"},\"@tags\":[\"success\",\"info\"],\"utc_time\":\"2019-05-07T09:56:33.996Z\",\"referer\":\"http://www.slate.com/success/thomas-marshburn\",\"agent\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.50 Safari/534.24\",\"clientip\":\"181.144.250.19\",\"bytes\":2553,\"host\":\"media-for-the-masses.theacademyofperformingartsandscience.org\",\"request\":\"/uploads/fyodor-yurchikhin.jpg\",\"url\":\"https://media-for-the-masses.theacademyofperformingartsandscience.org/uploads/fyodor-yurchikhin.jpg\",\"@message\":\"181.144.250.19 - - [2019-05-07T09:56:33.996Z] \\\"GET /uploads/fyodor-yurchikhin.jpg HTTP/1.1\\\" 200 2553 \\\"-\\\" \\\"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.50 Safari/534.24\\\"\",\"spaces\":\"this   is   a   thing    with lots of     spaces       wwwwoooooo\",\"xss\":\"<script>console.log(\\\"xss\\\")</script>\",\"headings\":[\"<h3>ulrich-walter</h5>\",\"http://www.slate.com/success/susan-still-kilrain\"],\"links\":[\"viktor-m-afanasyev@twitter.com\",\"http://twitter.com/security/stephen-oswald\",\"www.twitter.com\"],\"relatedContent\":[],\"machine\":{\"os\":\"win xp\",\"ram\":6442450944},\"@version\":\"1\"}\r",
    "host": "qvisbcld0051"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2019-05-09T09:09:32.167Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1557392972167
  ]
}
```

And that's what I have when I check my mapping:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "doc": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "message_field": {
            "path_match": "message",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "norms": false,
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              },
              "norms": false,
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "@message": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "agent": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "bytes": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "clientip": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "extension": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "geo": {
          "properties": {
            "coordinates": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "dest": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "src": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "srcdest": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "geoip": {
          "dynamic": "true",
          "properties": {
            "ip": {
              "type": "ip"
            },
            "latitude": {
              "type": "half_float"
            },
            "location": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "longitude": {
              "type": "half_float"
            }
          }
        },
        "host": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "ip": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "links": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "machine": {
          "properties": {
            "os": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "ram": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "text",
          "norms": false
        },
        "path": {
          "type": "text",
          "norms": false,
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "referer": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "relatedContent": {
          "properties": {
            "article:modified_time": {
              "type": "date"
            },
            "article:published_time": {
              "type": "date"
            },
            "article:section": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "article:tag": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "og:description": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "og:image": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "og:image:height": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "og:image:width": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "og:site_name": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "og:title": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "og:type": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "og:url": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "twitter:card": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "twitter:description": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "twitter:image": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "twitter:site": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "twitter:title": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "url": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "request": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "response": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "spaces": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "url": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "utc_time": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "xss": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    },
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "message_field": {
            "path_match": "message",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "norms": false,
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              },
              "norms": false,
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "geoip": {
          "dynamic": "true",
          "properties": {
            "ip": {
              "type": "ip"
            },
            "latitude": {
              "type": "half_float"
            },
            "location": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "longitude": {
              "type": "half_float"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I send my data thanks to logstash, so here's the conf of the input:

```
input {
  beats {
     port => 5044
     tags => "fromBeats"
  }
  file {
    path => [
    "/home/secunix/logs/*",
    "/tech/*"
    ]
    start_position => "beginning"

    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
  tcp {
    port => 5514
    type => "syslog"
    tags => "from Syslog-ng"
  } 
}

filter {
 if [type] == "syslog"{
    grok {
      match => ["message", "<(?<sys_priority>\d+?)>(?<syslog_timestamp>%{CISCOTIMESTAMP})\s(?<logsource>%{URIHOST})(\s(?:(?<application>.*?)(%(?<project>.*?))?))?:(?:\s)?(?<logmessage>.*$)"]
    }
    if [logmessage] {
      mutate {
        replace => [ "message", "%{logmessage}" ]
        remove_field => [ "logmessage" ]
      }
    }
    if [project]  {
      mutate {
        replace => [ "type", "%{project}" ]
        remove_field => [ "project" ]
      }
    }else if [application] {
      mutate {
        lowercase => [ "application" ]
      }
      mutate {
        gsub => [ "application", " ", "_" ]
      }
      mutate {
        replace => [ "type", "%{application}" ]
      }
    }else {
      mutate {
        replace => [ "type", "uknapp" ]
        add_field => { "application" => "uknapp" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the output:

```
output {
   elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        #+++ sa Added by scr-sop-af-config-elksandbox. Do not remove this line.
user => "logstash"
#--- sa Added by scr-sop-af-config-elksandbox. Do not remove this line.
        #+++ sa Added by scr-sop-af-config-elksandbox. Do not remove this line.
password => "logstash"
#--- sa Added by scr-sop-af-config-elksandbox. Do not remove this line.

   }
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can fix this please ?

Comment: You seem to be sending your data via Logstash, so your Logstash config file would be very useful, too.

Comment: I've added the conf file, thanks @Val for the advice

Comment: I think the problem is that in your filter you only have `if [type] == "syslog"` and data read from `/home/secunix/logs` do not have that type, so nothing from those files gets parsed and get sent in their raw form.

Comment: how can I know the type I use ? I've tried to remove the ```if [type] == "syslog"{...}``` but I still have the same result on the discover, I don't know if I have to put another log to update. But now I have a grok parse failure.@Val

Comment: You have `type => "syslog"` in your `tcp` input and the log line in the `message` field doesn't look like it's coming from syslog anyway. In my opinion you're trying to mix sources that are very different from each other, it's going to be hard to accommodate them all.

Comment: To clarify I've setup a sandbox on a linux virutal machine, adn I put by myself all logs. @Val how can I setup this filter to make it run on local with the logs I put into